# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges() - An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm running into a serious issue with my .NET console application.

The application parses JSONs and fills Model's properties with the parsed data. That part works. However, the other part, where it needs to insert it into the database - doesn't work.

This is the error:

```
An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

As far as I can tell, it's related to SaveChanges(), but I don't know what exactly.

This is my current code (a small part of it):

```
public static async Task UpdateDatabase() {
            Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Starting Database update...");

            using (var _context = new ReleasesDbContext()) {
                Console.WriteLine("[WAIT] Database update in progress... Please hold!");
                
                foreach (var release in AllReleases) {
                    _context.Releases.Add(release);
                    // Console.WriteLine($"{release.Id}) {release.ReleaseName} ({release.ReleaseId}) - {release.Stage}: {release.RunBy} ({release.StartedDate} - {release.CompletedDate}");
                    // _context.Add(release);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                // await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("[DONE] Successfully applied database update(s)!");
        }
```

Those commented lines are there because I was experimenting with all sorts of different stuff...

Also, this is my ReleasesDbContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ReleaseGet {
    public class ReleasesDbContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Release>? Releases { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"my_connection_string");
        }
    }
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that my model is pretty standard; I don't have anything special in it. Just about 20 properties, 2 of them are Int and the rest are String.

Really hoping for someone to help me as I've been stuck on this issue for hours. Thanks in advance, take care!

Update:
I forgot to post the full Exception. Here it is:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Releases' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
ClientConnectionId:4134dbf6-a8cb-485a-9c07-bcaa9a9a1e46
Error Number:544,State:1,Class:16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text. That includes the inner exception already. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup during debugging

Comment: The code is definitely not standard. The DbContext configuration is hard-coded, the data code is in a static method, the DbContext is created explicitly. The *standard* way in an ASP.NET Core application is to pass the DbContext into a controller or service using dependency injection, let DI dispose it and specify the actual database settings outside the context, in `AddDbContext`. Perhaps the hard-coded `my_connection_string` is the wrong one?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I've updated the original post and pasted the full Exception. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yeah, the code is wonky. This project actually started out as a simple console application for parsing JSONs and exporting the values to CSV. Now I need to update it and make it insert all those parsed values into the database. I've never done this before and as such I'm on thin ice here...

Comment: Did you check the inner exception? `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table ....`. That means one or more of the objects in `AllReleases` have an explicit ID but the table specifies that the ID column is automatically generated. You'd get the same error if you tried to execute `INSERT INTO Releases (ID,...) VALUES (1,...)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that could be it as I created the Releases table with Entity... So I should remove 'Id' from my model? The trouble is that I have 2 IDs: 'Id' and 'ReleaseId'. 'ReleaseId' is obtained from JSONs, and I'm manually setting the 'Id' as an ID of a Release object.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want the ID auto-generated or not. Not remove it. If you always specify the ID values explicitly, remove the `IDENTITY` constraint from the table field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I want to have it auto-generated. I'm not sure I understand this completely... If I keep the 'Id' in my model but disable my own 'auto-increment' (where I'm setting values for it), it should work? I mean, the 'Id' would then be empty for the whole execution time and would only change value once it reaches the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

After adding this **before** adding objects to my context, the insert works as expected!

```
_context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```